# how to make infinite loop for more than one function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my jquery code.this code contain three functions.this three function repeatedly execute for looping.but this code not run properly.how to make recursive call with three functions.the pid1,pid2,pid3 is

tag id's.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
     function animate() 
       {    
         $('#pid1').fadeOut(3000, function()
        {
         $(this).text('string1').fadeIn(3000);
        }); 
        animate1();
       }
     function animate1()
      {
       $('#pid2').fadeOut(3000, function()
       {
       $(this).text('string2').fadeIn(3000);
       });
       animate2();
      }
    function animate2() 
      {
       $('#pid3').fadeOut(3000, function()
       {
       $(this).text('string3').fadeIn(3000);
       });      
       animate();   
      }
   });
```

Comment: I think you need to add more text to your question - Do you want the lines to wait until next is finished? and so on? have a look at animate callbacks

Comment: You have a syntax error, can you fixe it ? Just to be sure.

Comment: this code used to change text repeatedly using recursive function.box1 and box2,box3 is <p> tag id.

Comment: I add correct code for you to end of my answer

Answer (score 1):

I want to share one pattern here:

```
var observer = {
  list: {},
  add: function(id, item){this.list[id] = item},
  del: function(id){delete this.list[id];},
  announce: function(data){
    for(var id in this.list){
      setTimeout(function(){
        this.list[id](data);
      }, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
observer.add('first', function(data){
  console.log('first', data);
})

observer.add('second', function(data){
  console.log('second', data);
})

var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){observer.announce(++i);}, 300);
```

You can to miss data parameter, or use all `arguments` then announce you subscibers...
This pattern equals how events work

I'm sorry, that I misunderstood question...
Here is correct code:

```
function foo1(){
  console.log(1);
  setTimeout(foo2, 1000);
}

function foo2(){
  console.log(2);
  setTimeout(foo1, 1000);
}

window.onload = foo1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function a() {
    /* stuff */ 
}
function b() {
    /* stuff */
}

var functionArray = [a(), b()];

$.each(functionArray, function(key, value) {

/* extra stuff while looping through functions */

});
```